# How to avoid crashing of android app on using gmail SMTP from multi devices

Tags: java, android

I have built an android app to send the user form data over email . I am using gmail SMTP to send the data from my app.

I am able to send the form's data over email from my device. However when someone else installs the app on their phone and try to submit form , app crashes & email is not sent.

I have tried activating the app password as well and activated the setting to allow less secure apps to send email using my gmail account. However still the app is crashing when someone else uses the app.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
                props.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
                props.put("mail.smtp.port","587");
```

Comment: What is the line that fails?

Comment: it simply comes out of the app to mobile's home screen. However on my device it works perfectly fine. I had received the security email as well that someone trying to access the account . I had marked that activity as safe but still its not working

Comment: you need to provide the error logs.

Comment: there is no error as such

Comment: for one of the users i got this error : " java.lang.RuntimeException:Canvas: trying  to draw too large(107773344bytes) bitmap at